# applicationDidFinishLaunching does not get triggered

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Trying to understand what mistake I am doing with the following code.
This is to be a Mac application, Xcode version 12.4. My problem is that `applicationDidFinishLaunching` never gets triggered.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var Delegate
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}


class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        let alert = NSAlert.init()
        alert.messageText = "Hello world"
        alert.informativeText = "Information text"
        alert.addButton(withTitle: "OK")
        alert.addButton(withTitle: "Cancel")
        alert.runModal()
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, you may want to use `UIAlertViewController` instead of `NSAlert`. Second, I don't think you can show the alert from AppDelegate as it is not a `UIViewController`. You need to present this from a `UIViewController` or your SwiftUI View.

Comment: @Todd, thank you. Alert code was working elsewhere, but I suppose you suggest that applicationDidFinishLaunching is actually being called but it is not a good place to tigger an alert ? Will double check this. Thank you.

Comment: @Todd this code is for MacOS not for iOS.

Comment: @RajaKishan Thank you for pointing that out. I missed that. In that case, the same thing applies where you want to launch it from `NSViewController` or a SwiftUI view rather than the App Delegate.

Comment: @Todd No. in mac it's fine to run alert with alert.runModal() no need viewcontroller.

Comment: @Todd it wasn't it, I managed to fix the code and alert runs fine there. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typing mistake. It's not an "a" it's a "_"

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) { //<here
        let alert = NSAlert.init()
        alert.messageText = "Hello world"
        alert.informativeText = "Information text"
        alert.addButton(withTitle: "OK")
        alert.addButton(withTitle: "Cancel")
        alert.runModal()
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. Almost. I needed to replace a with _ and then NSNotification with Notification. Working fine now. Thanks a lot.